# Using underscore in scala map function

Tags: scala

I have a function

```
val output2 = list
  .map(i =>
    if (i % 2 == 0) println("This is even number")
    else println("This is odd number")
  )
```

Can I use underscore in the lambda expression instead of i? If so how?

I read that if the variable is used only once in the expression you can replace the variable with `_`.

Comment: Can't use it inside an `if` condition. The underscore often looses or changes its meaning inside inner parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_` is useful only in simple expressions. If you still insist to see how your program should work with only `_`, you should have something like:

```
list.map(_ % 2 == 0) foreach { 
    if(_) println("This is even number") else println("This is odd number") 
}
```

Also note that your expression is not doing what you expecting it to do. The variable `output2` contains a list of 4 `Unit`s (`List((), (), (), ())`), which I guess is not what you originally wanted.